# Website being incorrectly marked down by PageSpeed Insights

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I have built a website using React with a Laravel backend. I use Laravel Mix (webpack) to minify the code for production.

```
Minifying https://amiibohunt.com/js/entry-client.js could save 323.9KiB (96% reduction) after compression. See optimized version.
```

This is the result I get from PageSpeed Insights, however when testing it with any other provider (YSlow, GTMetrix) it correctly detects it as being minified. When I click the "see optimised version" link, it gives me a file that cuts off and is missing 96% of the content.

The website in question is https://amiibohunt.com and I'd be grateful for any help with getting a better score.

Thanks!

Comment: consider PageSpeed Insights is just somthing like hints for improving your page speed and its score is not as your real page speed

Comment: Yes, I’m using it as a guide however it seems like a bug

Comment: It is a bug, the cause is that your JS file is too large, it seems to fail on anything that is already minified and still weighs over 1Mb, my guess is the minification algorithm it uses cannot cope with such massive files. That is one massive file, if you want to improve your score I would start there and remove any unused code.

Comment: I reduced the file size to 219KB and still get this error, I don't think my bundle size is that big especially in comparison to others that test successfully using PageSpeed Insights.